# How to increase the border width for select tags in kendo ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

Iam using kendo-ui for implementing select tags.

The border is appearing very light as you can see in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKDQV.png) but i want to increase the width of the border.

Below is my code my aim is to achieve to increase the size of the border.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // create ComboBox from input HTML element
   // create ComboBox from select HTML element
   $("#size").kendoComboBox();
   var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");
 });
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" role="application">
  <div id="tshirt-view" class="demo-section k-content">

    <h4 style="margin-bottom: .5em;">T-shirt Size</h4>
    <select id="size" placeholder="Select size..." style="width: 300px;">
      <option />X-Small
      <option />Small
      <option />Medium
      <option />Large
      <option />X-Large
      <option />2X-Large
    </select>


  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border is set on the wrappers with a class `k-dropdown-wrap`
You can therefore override the border width with:

```
.k-dropdown-wrap{
  border-width: 3px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/786epbmj/)

You need to add just one **CSS** line:

```
.k-combobox {
    border-width: 1px;
}
```